# Windows Identity Foundation 4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, wif

Is there a way to authenticate a user using WIF 4.5 and Membership provider? Please tell me more about claims. How can I pass my passowrd as a claim, as there are no Claim Types. Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start with the basics of claims based architectures. Look at these:

1. [An Introduction to Claims](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359101.aspx)
2. [Claims-Based Architectures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359108.aspx)

They are very generic introductions with little tie into specific implementations.